# Ctrl+C doesn't work in Guake Terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, terminal, fedora-19

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't interrupt the running command, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work either. But in Gnome Terminal everything is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is also the shortcut to copy something. So you have to bind the SIGKILL-shortcut to something else that the shortcut in the terminal works. For example with[AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/)

There was a ticket at guake.org three years ago which answer explains it well:

> Ctrl+C is historical key combination for killing foreground process in
>   unix terminals. Under the hood, it sends SIGINT ​signal to the
>   foreground process, and default effect of that is termination of the
>   process. However, any application is able to catch and block that
>   signal, ignoring the request for termination. Several dozens of other
>   signals exist with their specific functions, SIGSTOP for example
>   stopping the process (with possibility to resume later), SIGTERM
>   unconditionally terminating the process, etc.
>
> But, Ctrl+C is also widely known shortcut to "copying" operation,
>   ubiquitously used in MS Windows applications. Modern Linux desktop
>   environments emulate the behavior to cause less confusion to migrated
>   users, but the native selection system of X windows uses middle mouse
>   button for "copypasting" rather then hotkeys. Just select source text
>   and click with the third button in the destination area. Selected text
>   will be pasted.
>
> As Guake uses VTE component provided with GNOME (which is the one
>   responsible for handling ^C, the terminal killing one), I'm afraid, we
>   cannot help the conflict. Bind "copypasting" Ctrl+C to something other
>   (I have it binded to Ctrl+Shift+C) and get used to it; or try to
>   accommodate yourself with the middle click way - it's pretty
>   convenient indeed. And yeah, patches are as always welcome - so you
>   may try to fix everything yourself (though this is not a bug, this is
>   a conflict: nothing to fix, rather to find not-very-harmful
>   workaround).

[Source](http://guake.org/ticket/287)

Comment: OK, but in my case ctrl+C doesn't copy anything and is not bind to anything.

Comment: I would recommend you to try to remap the sigkill-command(ctrl+c in terminal) to another shortcut and than try it again.

Comment: I tried to change it by `stty intr \^k` not only it didn't work, I understood that non of my shortcuts work!

Comment: have you tried to re-install guake?

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't worked

Comment: Do any shortcuts work outside of the terminal?

Comment: Yes, they do. All of my gnome and gnome-terminal shortcuts work perfectly.

Comment: For linux, not Windows, CTRL+SHIFT+C and CTRL+SHIFT+V are for copy and paste respectively as CTRL+C is always kill the running command in the terminal as far as I have ever seen as this is essential. It appears the user is trying to kill the running code not copy and paste it appears the fact that CTRL+SHIFT+C is not working is subsequent to the issue.

Comment: I forgot I remapped my CTRL+SHIFT+C (and CTRL+SHIFT+V) to CTRL+C/V under the Guake Preferences. And of course why I'm here. Not sure why OP is having issues, however, my issue is was self induced and now solved.

Comment: Ctrl+C does not send SIGKILL, it sends SIGINT.